# Create log file for Java program

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a java program for which I created batch file to schedule it after some period to run.
I want to generate log file for that program whenever it get loaded,
that log file must contain date time and error if any thrown.

How to create log file for Java program?

Comment: your question is tagged with log4j. Do you've configured log4j to be used in your code ?

Answer (score 2):

If your needs are that simple, you can most likely do the logging in the batch file itself.

Do something like the following

```
date /t >> log_file_path
time /t >> log_file_path
echo Starting execution >> log_file_path
java -jar your_java_app 2>> log_file_path
echo Finished execution >> log_file_path
```

The `2>> log_file_path` means append the standard error stream to your log file, which will include any uncaught exceptions.

Comment: :you given above solution but where to write those all lines? in my java programme or in batch file ?

Comment: To quote myself: "in the batch file itself".

Answer (score 1):

Do Study about [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) logger, implement its configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file on the file system withe the FileWriter class and then initiate an I/O stream with BufferedWriter to write into this file:

```
// create a new file with specified file name
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("myFile.log");

// create the IO strem on that file
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

// write a string into the IO stream
bw.out("my log entry");

// don't forget to close the stream!
bw.close();
```

The whole thing must be surrounded with a try/catch in order to catch IO Exception.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've played around with basically the same idea as Marc. Just something simple you could look at for inspiration.

[here](http://computersciencecs.blogspot.dk/2012/12/java-simple-log-files.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple choices:

- Using command line redirection operators.
- Use I/O system and manually write to a file.
- Use log4j
- Use java.util.logging

Answer (score 0):

If you need something more complex, see [Java documentation for Logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

A simple form to create a Log and writes it to a file:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
FileHandler fileLog = new FileHandler("mylog.log");
logger.addHandler(fileLog);
```

Then you can use as a normal Logger:

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "my log line");
logger.log(Level.WARNING, "ATTENTION warning line");
```

You can visit this link for more info: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Logging/article.html